# How do you handle collision with a sprite?

Tags: c++, 2d, sprites, sdl2

I'm in the process of learning C++ and SDL2 and I'm trying to add a sprite to my player which is currently a rectangle. I've managed to get the sprite showing on the screen, however, I've run into a few issues such as the sprite not being positioned properly with the rectangle so it's like in the bottom right corner and going through solid objects and the sprite is positioned in the center, but the cube is a bit bigger so when colliding with walls or something above there is a bit of a gap. So I've been struggling a bit curious to see what I could do differently.

```
Player::Player(SDL_Renderer* renderer) : sprite(renderer, "assets/Spritesheet/Ninja Frog/Idle (32x32).png", 11, 32, 32) {
    printf("Player Ctor\n");
    position = Vector2(100, 100);
    velocity = Vector2(0, 0);
    size = Size(32 * 2, 32 * 2);
}

void Player::checkCollision(const std::vector<SDL_Rect>& rectangles) {
    for (auto rect : rectangles) {
        if (position.getX() < rect.x + rect.w &&
            position.getX() + size.getWidth() > rect.x &&
            position.getY() < rect.y + rect.h &&
            position.getY() + size.getHeight() > rect.y) {
            // Collision Detected 

            // Determine which side the collision occurred on
            double leftCollision = std::fabs((position.getX() + size.getWidth()) - rect.x);
            double rightCollision = std::fabs(position.getX() - (rect.x + rect.w));
            double topCollision = std::fabs((position.getY() + size.getHeight()) - rect.y);
            double bottomCollision = std::fabs(position.getY() - (rect.y + rect.h));

            // Determine the minimum collision distance
            std::vector<double> collisions = { leftCollision, rightCollision, topCollision, bottomCollision };
            double minCollision = *std::min_element(collisions.begin(), collisions.end());

            if (minCollision == leftCollision) {
                // Collision on the left side of the player
                position.setX(rect.x - size.getWidth());
            }
            else if (minCollision == rightCollision) {
                // Collision on the right side of the player
                position.setX(rect.x + rect.w);
            }
            else if (minCollision == topCollision) {
                // Collision on the top side of the player
                position.setY(rect.y - size.getHeight());
                velocity.setY(0);  
                isGrounded = true;
                jumpsLeft = totalJumps;
                coyoteTimeCounter = coyoteTime; 
            }
            else if (minCollision == bottomCollision) {
                // Collision on the bottom side of the player
                position.setY(rect.y + rect.h);
                velocity.setY(0); 
            }
        }
    }
}

void Player::draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer) {
    //SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    //SDL_Rect rect = { position.getX(), position.getY(), size.getWidth(), size.getHeight() };
    //SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);

    sprite.draw(renderer, position.getX(), position.getY(), size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
}
```

```
void Sprite::draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    SDL_Rect dstRect;
    dstRect.x = x;
    dstRect.y = y;
    dstRect.w = width;
    dstRect.h = height;

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, &frames[currentFrame], &dstRect);
}
```

Comment: Spatial/geometric problems are often easier to understand with a diagram or screenshot. Consider adding one to help attract better answers, faster